# How to get approval for a particular task in django

Tags: django, api, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am working on creating tasks, in which I require have a url for approvals. In this, the person that created the task instance can ask for approval for some changes from another user (not necessarily admin). These approval requests will show up on the approver's dashboard in form of a table, where he can approve/reject them.
Here is my code:

models.py:

```
class Approvals(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task_category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    requester = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='Requester', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    priority = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    approver = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='Approver', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    due_date = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

views.py:

```
class PendingApprovals(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    http_method_names = ["get","update"]
    queryset = Approvals.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ApprovalSerializer
    to_approved = Approvals.objects.filter(approver=request.user,approved='False')
```

I am able to get a list of all the tasks that a given user has to approve, but I cant figure out how to approve them i.e how to change their boolean field tag.
Any help will be appreciated. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

You could always add a method to your model so that you can access it via Approvals.set_approval() and toggle the current approval status of it.

```
class Approvals(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task_category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    requester = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='Requester', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    priority = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    approver = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='Approver', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    due_date = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def set_approval(self):
        self.approved = not self.approved
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate how will it help